# Is the adjective "practical" appropriate for describing skills that involve hands-on experiences in a specific discipline?

Tags: word-choice

Suppose that in an interview an applicant who have received a master's in computer engineering wants to say that in addition to the theoretical lessons and studies in the university, he also have done practical projects, such as programming a software, and have developed some skills while doing these projects. In the first place, I thought that the following sentence is a good one and *practical* is a suitable adjective here:

> In addition to theoretical knowledge, I have also developed my practical skills.

But I saw [this](https://thttps://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-are-practical-skills.3583235/) page where it has been said that practical skill can be anything, like replacing tire, using Microsoft word, and cooking. It made me doubtful if it is a good adjective here because it may be too general. Employer may think "what does replacing tires and cooking have to do with this programming job position?"

Comment: "Practical" has several meanings. Have you looked them up in a dictionary to see which ones fit your context?

Comment: @gotube Yes and before seeing this page I was sure that it is a good choice here. Even now I am 90% sure but wanted to be sure that it does not convey any unsolicited meaning in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty clear that if he is talking about computer programming, then "practical skills" means "practical skills in computer programming".  English, is just like any other natural language in this way.

Compare:

> I am an excellent gardener; I have detailed knowledge of different plants and excellent practical skills.

> I am an excellent computer programmer;  I have a deep understanding of computer science and excellent practical skills.

Is there any doubt that the first person is talking about practical skills in gardening, and the second person isn't?

Comment: Sure the context clear things up. For expanding my range of vocabulary, can I also use "hands-on skills" and "experimental skills" in this context equivalently?